# Same identifier in an 2 different enum in same namespace in different files

Tags: c++

I am using same namespace in two different files.
In those files i have 2 enum. 
I need to use same identifiers in those enum.
Is there a way to do it?

In first file
first.h

```
...
namespace foo
{
 enum direction
 {
   NONE, 
   RIGHT    
   ...
 }
}

In second file
second.h

...
namespace foo
{
 enum reverse
 {
   NONE,  
   LEFT,   
   ...
 }
}
```

This is a sample code.
I need to reuse "NONE". 
I need code for visual studio 2008.
(Cannot use : enum class)

Comment: This gives a compiler error: `error C2365: 'NONE' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'`. You need to change your naming conventions using different symbols inside the enumeration.

Comment: Because of how plain enumerations works, there is unfortunately no way of using the same symbols for multiple enumerations in the same namespace. You must use different symbols for different enumerations in the same namespace.

Comment: Or you could use `enum class`.

Comment: @Hiura cant use enum class

Answer (score 5):

If you can use C++11, the best way to achieve what you want is to use "strongly typed enums", declared using the `enum class` keywords, i.e.

```
enum class direction
{
    NONE,
    LEFT
};

enum class reverse
{
    NONE,
    RIGHT
};
```

In the rest of your code, you then refer to the enumerators as `ns::direction::NONE` and `ns::reverse::NONE` (like in C#, if you're familiar with that language).

If you don't have C++11 available, then you can simulate the same thing by declaring an anonymous enum in an inner namespace, for example

```
namespace direction {
     enum {
         NONE,
         LEFT
     };
}

namespace reverse {
    enum {
        NONE,
        RIGHT
    };
}
```

Again, you then refer to `direction::NONE` and `reverse::NONE`, so there is no conflict.

Comment: Thanks, but Cant use C++11, also need to use same namespace.

Comment: @Coder89, I believe you have an artificially complex problem.. Why can't you add an extra namespace (potentially nested)? Alternative to namespace would be a struct.

Comment: @Hiura It is to bring all enum values in various files[10 files] into same namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
direction::NONE
```

and

```
reverse::NONE
```

to distinguish the enumerators provided that the enumerations are defined in  different scopes. Otherwise the compiler will issue an error of redefinition of an enumerator.

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>

enum A { NONE };

namespace N1
{
    enum B { NONE = 1 };
}

int main() 
{
    enum C { NONE = 2 };

    std::cout << A::NONE << '\t' << N1::NONE << '\t' << NONE << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0   1   2
```

Comment: @sjdowling You are wrong. It is a valid code according to the new C++ Standard. The demonstrative example I showed I compiled at www.ideone.com

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "first.h"

namespace second
{
    #include "second.h"
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << foo::NONE << " " << second::foo::NONE << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't reuse the values from one enum to another.

This is probably NOT the right solution, but you can either use explicit enum values, e.g.

```
 enum ... 
 {
    NONE = 0,
    ...
 };
```

or rely on the compiler starting with 0 and counting up one for each enumeration (assuming no assignment).

However, they are still not the same enum type, and I think you should consider a different solution. It's not entirely clear from your question what you are actually trying to achieve, but it sounds like you are trying to make a "reverse control", where left becomes right and right becomes left, etc. I would suggest having a getter function that does something like this:

```
direction GetDirection()
{
    if (reverse)
    {
       switch(curDirection) 
       {
          case LEFT:
              return RIGHT;
          case RIGHT:
              return LEFT;
         ...  deal with other directions that need reversing ... 
       }
    }
    return curDirection;
}
```

Another option is to implement two classes, where one does a "reverse switch", and the other just returns the current direction without reversing.